# Why etree.find doesn't find the element for the provided example

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

Lets suppose it has this:

```
xml_as_str = '''
<v1:Header>
    <v2:Person>Foo Bar</v2:Person>
    <v2:Email>foo@bar.com</v2:Email>
</v1:Header>
'''

from lxml import etree
tree = etree.fromstring(xml_as_str, etree.XMLParser(recover=True))
```

How could it get the value of certain tag, e.g "Foo Bar" for v2:Person ?

I've tried this:

```
 >> tree.find('.//v2:Person')
 >> tree.find('.//{Person}v2')
```

in order to get the element and then `.text`, but `.find` doesn't find the element, why?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `local-name()` xpath function:

```
>>> xml_as_str = '''
... <v1:Header>
...     <v2:Person>Foo Bar</v2:Person>
...     <v2:Email>foo@bar.com</v2:Email>
... </v1:Header>
... '''
>>>
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.fromstring(xml_as_str, etree.XMLParser(recover=True))
>>> tree.xpath('//*[local-name()="v2:Person"]/text()')[0]
'Foo Bar'
```

Comment: Thanks @falsetru, that works! but why the `.find` doesn't not work in this case?

Comment: @trinchet, `find` does not support all xpath expression.

Answer (score 0):

You could use BeautifulSoup also.

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: xml_as_str = '''
   ...: <v1:Header>
   ...:     <v2:Person>Foo Bar</v2:Person>
   ...:     <v2:Email>foo@bar.com</v2:Email>
   ...: </v1:Header>
   ...: '''
In [9]: soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_as_str, 'lxml')
In [15]: for i in soup.find_all('v1:header'):
    ...:     for j in soup.find_all('v2:person'):
    ...:         print(j.text)
    ...:         
Foo Bar

In [16]:
```

Through List-Comprehension.

```
In [17]: [j.text for i in soup.find_all('v1:header') for j in soup.find_all('v2:person')][0]
Out[17]: 'Foo Bar'
```